# ISC DHCP server: how to use "reserved" statement

Tags: isc-dhcp

I've been looking online, cannot find a single example of how to use the "reserved" statement. Supposedly it goes into the dhcpd.leases file. Stop dhcpd, edit the file, and restart. But it doesn't seem to be working because after restarting it disappears from the file. Can someone give an actual example of where/how to use it and the procedure for making it work?

Answer (score 0):

After more digging I finally across this: [how to set the reserved flag using OMAPI](https://lists.isc.org/pipermail/dhcp-users/2008-June/006519.html)

Apparently this can be done only from the omshell command, and there's an undocumented bit operator for the flag in order to set it. I followed the instructions, and the lease file does show "reserved" now. I dont' know how to test it, though.